# Is there a way to convert a string to plaintext in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
searched_parameter = '0.0'
number_of_ocurrences = result.count(searched_parameter)
print(number_of_ocurrences)
sentences = re.findall(r'([^.]+0.0+[^.](?:.\d+)?)', result)
print(sentences)
```

Is there a way I can put searched_parameter into an array and put the array index into the sentences line instead of hard coding the value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an f-string to substitute the variable into the regexp.

```
sentences = re.findall(rf'([^.]+{re.escape(searched_parameter)}+[^.](?:.\d+)?)', result)
```